# Appearance of closed projects in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

The list of all the projects we work stay (even after we close them) in the Package Explorer window of the Eclipse, they never vanish off the window. This behavior of Eclipse really irritates, specially if we have worked with many projects.

Are there any settings in Eclipse which makes closed projects goes off the window?

(Closed projects vanishes in Netbeans by default)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Package Explorer click on the small arrow in the top right side. 
Select "Filters...", and mark "Closed Projects" in the list of elements to exclude.

Comment: There seem to be no arrow like that!

Comment: Strange.. Perhaps the keyboard shortcut is working: CTRL+F10 inside the Package Explorer

Comment: Of course I found that arrow (or CTRL+F10) > Customize view >Filter > Then check closed projects.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Working Sets](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cworkset.htm).  This sounds what you may be looking for, in terms of keeping your workspace clean.

Comment: +1, this is exactly what I use Working Sets for. Before I discovered it, I was using multiple workspaces, which sucked.

Answer (score 0):

You can Delete the project -- it will be gone from the workspace.  You also have the option to physically delete the files, but you probably don't want to do that)